# How to find clients for IT freelancing

Tags: freelance-websites, remote, group-freelancing

I have been looking for clients for quite some time.  I'm an IT freelancer.  **Besides** the usual Google search and freelance web sites I ask to know about other sources.

After reading initial answers which included suggestions of web sites I thought to delete the question.  Perhaps my writing 'Besides' in the question didn't help.  Since I wrote the original question I have not found answers.  I looked at other similar questions but again saw upwork and freelancer and usual advice.  Since my original writing I have become convinced that freelancing in IT is not feasible and would advise people to research as much as possible before depending on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a job then you should register your account at these freelancing sites like freelancer.com,upwork,fiverr,linkdin,Guru etc and try to find clients according to your criteria.

Comment: upwork and freelancer.com are a joke. I have just seen there a work to write a provisioning application and corredponding infractruture setup for a cable provider, a job/set of projects for 10k-100k depending on your part of the world, being priced as 1k. and at 10-20k upfront commision to the site, it is an insult

Answer (score 0):

Have you found sites but not getting the jobs, or not found sites?

Stackoverflow, Linkedin, jobserve.com are just some of the many that are out there. It might well be that your location goes against you. My clients want me on site, not work from home. The jobs that are available for you to do from home are fraught with difficulty and risk and their availability will vary tremendously based on your skillset.

Comment: Found sites. No jobs. I use linkedin but no success.

Comment: Its a numbers game. Try one site and you have fewer chances than two sites. I spend an hour or two a day searching for jobs across a number of sites. Some days are more successful than others. I can expect to apply for ten or more jobs a week and lucky if half reply and possibly one in ten might end up with a talk on the phone. Interviews are less frequent. If freelancing was so easy, more would do it. Be creative and more active and you will be more successful in your search. Best of luck.

Comment: Sounds very difficult to do.  I'm having second thoughts about it.  It would seem that a huge percent of the time is spent on overhead.